# Spinner not displaying Emails

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

```
final Spinner emailsList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.email_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getUserEmails());
    emailsList.setAdapter(adapter);

public ArrayList<String> getUserEmails() {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    ArrayList<String> possibleEmails = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        possibleEmails.add(account.name);
    }
    return possibleEmails;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

XML

```
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/email_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:hint="List of emails"
            android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
            android:textSize="11dp" />
```

Please help why it is not displaying emails in a spinner, as it is not showing an error, just showing a warning as follows

```
03-16 11:15:58.910 16209-16209/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
```

Comment: which target sdk are you using and on which android os are you testing ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 20, targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: not android studio version. Your android mobile os version/ Emulator os version. Like Android 8.0

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Sorry its Android N 7.0

Comment: Any solution you can recommend for higher sdk Pls. ?

Comment: Ok will do that thank you for your time

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314685/android-spinner-prompt-not-working